# CORS Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: laravel, angular, cors

I am working on an angular 2 app that communicates with a Laravel powered REST API. I'm trying to send a patch request to the REST API and getting the above error. In the network tab of developer tools my response headers look correct and seem to disprove the error message.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
Allow: GET,HEAD,PATCH
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Acess-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-XSRF-TOKEN
```

Comment: You can see that "Acess" is spelled wrong...right? VTC - simple typo.

Comment: Oh wow. Yeah that should have been obvious

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because PATCH methods are not allowed by default and you have to actually send POST method with

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

in the form tag.

That's how I do it, not sure how it's with Angular.

Comment: Nah I'm using the $http service that has a patch method. My issue was a stupid typo on the response headers.